# Can a NativeScript viewModel have "computed" properties?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, observable, nativescript

Say I had a simple viewModel where the property `foo` should be just like any other, only that it's generated/computed with the value of another property and updates whenever the other one updates:

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
        name: 'John',
        foo() {
            return 'Hello ' + viewModel.name; //not really what I'm looking for
        }
    });

    return viewModel;
}
```

Knockout.js has these "computed" observables, which I find very handy in many places. This is what it would look like with Knockout.js:

```
function HomeViewModel() {
    const viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable('John'),
        foo: ko.pureComputed(() => 'Hello ' + viewModel.name())
    };

    return viewModel;
}
```

Is there something similar in NativeScript?

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript Core is very light weight, no fancy features like computed out of the box. But there is `propertyChangeEvent` which you may utilise to update `foo` whenever `name` is changed.

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
 var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
  name: "John",
  foo: ""
 });
 viewModel.on("propertyChange", function (event) {
  const propertyName = event.propertyName;
  if (propertyName === "name") {
    viewModel.set("foo", "Hello " + event.value);
  }
 });
 // To compute initial value for `foo` 
 viewModel.notifyPropertyChange("name", viewModel.get("name"), viewModel.get("name"));
 return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

[Here is a playground sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=b1k9zg).

I would suggest migrating to Angular / Vue if you looking for fancy features like computing, dynamic templates etc., with handy syntax. I haven't used Knockout, but I guess it could be integrated with with NativeScript just like the way Angular / Vue today with some decent effort - end of the day everything is just JavaScript ;)

Comment: Thank you. Though I'm already aware of the `propertyChange` handler, I don't really like it, because it gets triggered whenever any property changes, even if I only want to listen to a single one. That's why I am/was hoping there would be another way. Plus, this only works within the viewModel. If I had another model who's property I'd like to use instead of `name` in my example, I couldn't do that. -- Don't know if Knockout could be ported. But I guess since Angular and Vue have been ported, it should be possible. (Though I couldn't do it since I'm just a "consumer" of the framework ^_^)